Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state QueryFailedError (nestjs + mysql2 + typeorm)
I have an issue after some hours of work and I need restart the server.
ERROR \[TypeOrmLogger\] Error: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state QueryFailedError: Can't add new command when connection is in closed state at Query.onResult
InfraModule.ts
export const databaseProviders = [
  {
    provide: InfraDITokens.DataSource,
    useFactory: async () => {
      return addTransactionalDataSource(AppDataSource).initialize();
    },
  },
];

@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [...providers, ...databaseProviders],
  exports: [
    InfraDITokens.DataSource,
    InfraDITokens.EmailSenderService,
    InfraDITokens.FyGatewayService,
  ],
})
export class InfraModule implements OnApplicationBootstrap {
  onApplicationBootstrap(): void {}
}

data-source.ts
export default new DataSource({
  name: 'default',
  type: 'mysql',
  host: DatabaseConfig.DB_HOST,
  port: DatabaseConfig.DB_PORT,
  username: DatabaseConfig.DB_USERNAME,
  password: DatabaseConfig.DB_PASSWORD,
  database: DatabaseConfig.DB_NAME,
  synchronize: DatabaseConfig.IS_SYNCHRONIZE,
  logging: DatabaseConfig.DB_LOG_ENABLE ? 'all' : false,
  logger: DatabaseConfig.DB_LOG_ENABLE ? TypeOrmLogger.new() : undefined,
  entities: [`${TypeOrmDirectory}/entity/**/*{.ts,.js}`],
  migrations: [`${TypeOrmDirectory}/migration/**/*{.ts,.js}`],
  migrationsTransactionMode: 'all',
});

I've been trying to resolve it for days and I can't find a solution.
Thanks for any help.
try update typeorm, mysql2 versions.
Using mysql module it happen the same error.
search docs about the problem.
